# When you are sad that something ended but you were glad it happened

Tags: emotions

Like if you had a really amazing friend for 10 years but they had to leave your city and you were really sad that they had to leave but you were glad that you got to meet and experience your life with each other, and then you would remind yourself of all the great memories you had together but the reality was that you had to leave each other.

If anyone has ever seen gladiator (spoilers for those who haven't seen it) this is a good example of what I am talking about. In the movie Juba and Maximus have been fighting for freedom for a very long time but at the end of the film Maximus sacrifices himself for Juba and the Roman empire. Then Juba is seen on a rock, almost reminiscing about his memories of Maximus and he says almost like Maximus is listening from the afterlife "I will see you again... but not yet... not yet..." with hope, but also with an underlying deep sorrow for his dead friend, but he was glad that they got to do what they did, and that he was glad that maybe he could see his friend again maybe some day.

Comment: I saw the spoiler warning but couldn't stop me reading it all. :(

Comment: Sometimes one needs Tennyson: ['Tis better to have loved and lost than never to have loved at all.](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/a/alfredlord153702.html)

Comment: This isn't a question. Presumably you want a word or a phrase, but come on, at least tell us which!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**bittersweet**

"bittersweet" in American English
- containing a mixture of sadness and happiness
- Feeling pleasure and happiness

"The bittersweet end to the movie is just right."

(Definition of bittersweet from the Cambridge Academic Content Dictionary © Cambridge University Press)

*that movie ending (I've seen it) also expresses a sense of liberation, redemption, of glory *and* tragedy, so "bittersweet" may not have the poignancy you're looking for...

Answer (score 0):

Applying a oxymoron like bittersweet is a good fit in terms of addressing the emotional ambiguity.

Depending on what exactly you are trying to express, you might also consider using a metaphor such as to feel "torn" or synesthesia such as "feeling blue".
But you could also stick with established words/phrases such as:

- having a feeling of nostalgia,
- feeling ambivalence in regard to,
- feeling pensive,
- being struck by a reflective mood.

I hope this helps :)